# Execute commands after pg_dump ends

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I want to execute commands after pg_dump ends. Example

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
    _attempts integer = 1;
    _pid integer;

BEGIN   
    _pid = (SELECT pid FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE application_name = 'pg_dump');
    WHILE (_pid IS NOT NULL) LOOP
        RAISE INFO 'Attempts=%, pid=%', _attempts, _pid;        
        PERFORM pg_sleep(5);
        _pid = (SELECT pid FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE application_name = 'pg_dump');
        _attempts = _attempts + 1;
    END LOOP;

    SELECT 1;
    ...;
END$$;
```

But the problem is that even after the dump ends, the cycle becomes infinite and I have to interrupt it manually. Raise info continues to output the same pid. If I manually repeat at this moment

```
SELECT pid FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE application_name = 'pg_dump'
```

then it does not return anything. I already realized that this is due to the transaction. Is there any way to solve such a problem without a transaction?

If there is no dump initially, then of course the statements after the loop are executed successfully.

Comment: Why not put those commands into the shell script that starts `pg_dump`?

Comment: Can't do that due to network topology and security policy

Comment: This is a typical XY problem. What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to execute some commands after a dump that are blocked by this dump to avoid all derivative locks